# I have only one Elastic IP and still its billing me- $0.005 per Elastic IP address not attached to a running instance per hour (prorated)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I tried and practiced with multiple instances and allocated a few Elastic IPs to those, but soon I removed all instances and Elastic IPs that were not required and maintained one instance and two Elastic IPs.

I released an Elastic IP that wasn't in use (*which I think was billed for*) 24hr. earlier but the hours in the invoice still increased and billed me more.

Still **I am billed for Elastic IP address not attached to a running instance per hour (prorated)** when I don't even have any such lying around.
I know only the first elastic IP is free, this current IP might not be the first one I created.

Below is the snapshot of the Elastic IP addressess panel of aws-

[image]

My invoice -

[image]

When I released the unallocated IP my hours in the bill were 131 now its 150 why so?

Comment: Had you tried to reach AWS support?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the US East Ohio region in the top screenshot?

Comment: @tym32167 No I haven't contacted AWS support yet

Comment: @MarkB Yes its US East Ohio region

Comment: I would file an AWS billing support ticket.

Comment: I billing hours have now stuck at 150 so I am assuming the bill got updated after a delay and hence now all the hours have been added. Still thank yous guys for helping